# A question in Theorem 5 of Lesson 8 of Hoffman Kunze linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I am self studying Linear Algebra from Hoffman Kunze and I have a question in a theorem of Lesson-8 of text book.

Adding it's image:

[image]

> How does it follows from Theorem 4 that E(c$\alpha + \beta) = cE\alpha + E\beta$ ?

Image of Statement of Theorem 4:

[image]

Kindly tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
E(c\alpha + \beta) = cE\alpha + E\beta &\iff cE\alpha + E\beta \text{ is the best approximation in $W$ of $c\alpha + \beta$}\\
&\stackrel{(i)}\iff (cE\alpha + E\beta) - (c\alpha + \beta) \perp W\\
&\iff c(E\alpha -\alpha) + (E\beta - \beta) \perp W
\end{align}
and the last statement is true. Namely, $E\alpha$ is the best approximation in $W$ of $\alpha$ so by $(i)$ we get $E\alpha -\alpha \perp W$. Similarly $E\beta - \beta \perp W$. Therefore $c(E\alpha -\alpha) + (E\beta - \beta) \perp W$.

Comment: how does E(c$\alpha+ \beta$) implies cE($\alpha$) +E($\beta$) is best approximation of W in c $\alpha$ + $\beta$ ? Can you please prove it.

Comment: @User $E(c\alpha + \beta)$ is by definition the best approximation of $c\alpha + \beta$ by vectors in $W$. Therefore $E(c\alpha + \beta) = cE\alpha + E\beta$ means that $cE\alpha + E\beta$ is the best approximation of $c\alpha + \beta$ by vectors in $W$.